# How to find the right Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to Json and trying to load a part of a Json object. The structure is:

```
{
  "Monday": {
    "title": "Magic Monday",
    "text": "On Magic Monday, all the food disappears.",
    "image": "images/special.jpg",
    "color": "red"
  },

  "Tuesday": {
    "title": "Twofer Tuesday",
    "text": "Two vegetables for the price of one!.",
    "image": "images/special.jpg",
    "color": "green"
  }
}
```

I have a variable, weekDay, which I am going to use to find the right object. When this is found, I want to use the value of title and text in my HTML.

So far I have the code:

```
$.getJSON('data/specials.json', function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (entryIndex, entry) {
    var html = '<h4>' + entry['title'] + '</h4>';
    html += '<p>' + entry['text'] + '</p>';
    $('#details').append(html);
  });
});
```

But I do not know, how to only get the title and the text from the object with the right weekday.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
var weekDay = "Tuesday";
```

then you can simply use

```
var entry = data[weekDay];
```

and then

```
var title = entry.title;
```

or

```
var title = entry['title'];
```

[This document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) explains how you access object properties.